# Show loading form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have an application where I need to display a loading form on some actions. So, I have a button that opens a form, and when I click on this button I need to display my loading form. I use the following code:

```
private void diligênciasToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
LoadingWindow loadingWindow = new LoadingWindow();
try
 {
  loadingWindow.Show();
  Cursor.Current = Classe_Cursor.LoadCustomCursor(@"D:\Wait (1).ani");
  FormConsultaDiligencia Childform = new FormConsultaDiligencia();
  Childform.MdiParent = this;
  Childform.Show();
  Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
  loadingWindow.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  MessageBox.Show("" + ex.Message);
 }
}
```

When I click this button the LoadingWindow opens, but the items that I have inside the form don't work:
[image]

All appears like blank, and it would appear like:

[image]

What is happening here? I can't get there alone, can someone explain to me what is the problem?

Comment: Whitch version of .Net Framework you use?

Comment: Are thre screen refreshs after you show the form? Or is your CPU busy?

Comment: So, is it your goal for `loadingWindow` to show during the creation and initialization of `Childform` (which takes a long time), and then to be hidden?

Comment: @Vlad, 4.5 Framework

Comment: @adv12, yes, it may appear only during the initialization  of the childform

Comment: @Reznor13, why does it take so long to initialize `ChildForm`?  Does it just have a lot of controls, or does it do a bunch of I/O (loading files, etc.)?  There's not much that can be done to improve your code unless `FormConsultaDiligencia` can be sped up or parts of it can be done on a background thread.  But you can't use a background thread for anything that modifies GUI elements.

Comment: @adv12, That form contains a DataGridView that loads like 150k records. Also, I have to resize the columns programmatically and I think that is the problem

Comment: @Reznor13, then honestly, it sounds like you're stuck.  The loading form isn't getting refreshed because the UI thread is tied up with loading your `DataGridView`, and it sounds like the long operations in `FormConsultaDiligencia` need to modify the GUI and therefore can't be moved to a background thread.  You could avoid the upfront loading hit of the `DataGridView` by using `VirtualMode`, but that doesn't help if you're then going to walk through each row to calculate column widths.

Comment: You will want to make note of @Servy's comment on your answer. There are better ways to architect what you've posted.  (I moved your answer to an answer)

Comment: @Reznor13 Do you want to use progressbar instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because you show form and execute prolonged operations into GUI thread. You should execute this operations in backgroung thread.
**EDIT**: code removed.

Comment: Your explanatory text is okay, but this code appears to simply delay tying up the UI thread.  Everything within that `Invoke()` is going to happen synchronously on the UI thread even though `Invoke` is called from a background thread.

Comment: your updated code still has a problem in that now you're modifying controls from a background thread, which is not allowed.

Comment: You're creating `ChildForm` on a background thread.  All the initialization in `FormConsultaDiligencia` is being done on the background thread, and then you're setting `MdiParent` and showing the form on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes. But creating form into background thread - is allowed operation. `Show` must be executed on UI thread

Comment: The UI thread for a form is the thread on which it was created.  If you construct `ChildForm` on abackground thread, the only thread from which you're allowed to call `ChildForm` is that background thread.  The call to `Invoke` makes `ChildForm.MdiParent` and `ChildForm.Show` happen on the *main* form's UI thread, which is the main thread of the application but not `ChildForm`'s UI thread.

Comment: Author found solution. So I remove code. @adv12, thanks for your  explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After the istruction loadingWindow.Show() the click function is hang by loadingWindow that seems no filled with components.

The code restart from Cursor.Current = Classe_Cursor.LoadCustomCursor(@"D:\Wait (1).ani") after the user close the loadingWindow.

The istruction loadingWindow.Close() is an error: at that point the loadingWindow is already closed.

I guess you have to load animation and strings in constructor of loadingWindow.

Anyway I think you need to use a thread to perform the creation of Childform. At the end that thread will send a close request to loadingWindow and start to show Childform.

Solution proposed by  adv12 will be your gol easely.